# when receive data, [serialport_datareceived] event occur more than once(using virtual serial port)

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm trying to send data and receive through serial communication using virtual serial port program. But here is problem...
Let's suppose A is transmit data and B is receive data.

When A send data to B. B receive data twice(serialport_datareceived event occur twice!).

Every time when B close serialport and open again, serialport_datareceived event occur increase.

I can't figure out why is this happening.

```
A(transmit)
BaudRate = 9600
Parity = None
DataBits = 8
StopBits = 1

    public transmit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (String s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            cBoxPort.Items.Add(s);          
        }
    }
    private void CBoxBaudRate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxBaudRate.Text);                          
    }
    private void CBoxStopBits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cBoxStopBit.Text);   
    }
    private void CBoxDataBits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxDataBits.Text);                          
    }
    private void CBoxParityBits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cBoxParity.Text);           
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = cBoxPort.Text;
            serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxBaudRate.Text);
            serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxDataBits.Text);
            serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cBoxStopBit.Text);
            serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cBoxParity.Text);
            serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
            serialPort1.Open();

            txtReceive.AppendText("Connected\n");   
            btnConnect.Enabled = false;             
            btnClose.Enabled = true;
            btnSend.Enabled = true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();                        
            btnClose.Enabled = false;
            btnConnect.Enabled = true;
            btnSend.Enabled = false;
            txtReceive.AppendText("Disconnected\n");  
        }
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytesend = { 0x00 };
        Debug.WriteLine("111");
        serialPort1.Write(bytesend, 0, bytesend.Length);
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("444");
    }

}
```

B(receive)

```
    byte[] bytesend;

    //Initial Conditions(SerialPort)
    private void receive_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cBoxBaudRate.SelectedIndex = 0;     //BaudRate = 9600
        cBoxParity.SelectedIndex = 0;       //Parity = None
        cBoxDataBits.SelectedIndex = 0;     //DataBits = 8
        cBoxStopBit.SelectedIndex = 0;      //StopBits = 1
        cBoxPort.SelectedIndex = 1;         

        btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        btnClose.Enabled = false;
    }

    //Show usable CommPort
    public receive()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (String s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            cBoxPort.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }

    //Connection
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = cBoxPort.Text;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxBaudRate.Text);
        serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxDataBits.Text);
        serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cBoxStopBit.Text);
        serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cBoxParity.Text);
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
        serialPort1.Open();

        btnConnect.Enabled = false;
        btnClose.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            btnClose.Enabled = false;
            btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("222");
    }
```

when i debug this code output represent 111 222 222. And when i press the close and connect button, the output represent 111 222 222 222.

Comment: On your "connect" buttons, you're wiring up the DataReceived event EACH time.  You only want to do this ONCE, like in the Load() event of the Form...

Comment: thanks for your comment. but if you don't mind, could you write comment more precisely?

Comment: I heard that it happens because of multi-thread. Am i right? if it happens because of multi-thread problem, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time when B close serialport and open again,
>   serialport_datareceived event occur increase.

Right, because like I said, you should only be wiring up the DataReceived event ONCE.  Each time you click the button another handler gets added, resulting in the multiple firing for a single receive.  This has nothing to do with multi-threading.  Move the line that wires up the handler from the button click event up to the Load event:

```
private void transmit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived); // now it only gets called once
    // ... other existing code ...
}


private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = cBoxPort.Text;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxBaudRate.Text);
        serialPort1.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(cBoxDataBits.Text);
        serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cBoxStopBit.Text);
        serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cBoxParity.Text);
        // serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);  // remove this line
        serialPort1.Open();

        txtReceive.AppendText("Connected\n");   
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;             
        btnClose.Enabled = true;
        btnSend.Enabled = true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

You need to do the same thing in your receive form as well.

Comment: Idle_Mind is correct.  You can write your program to read only when the button is clicked or to read whenever data appears but not both.  Pick the one that will suit your application best.

Comment: He could also do a `-=` in his close function.